# How to check a string null in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do you check a string for "null" in Dart? (not a `null` object)

is there some Dart SDK API like Java's `equals`?

Comment: Do you mean check if there the string 'null' is stored in your string , i..e if your string == 'null'?

Answer (score 7):

I believe isEmpty property will return false since if your string is null, it still holds an object and won't be empty. So depending on what you mean in your post.

If you want to check for the string 'null', just do

```
if (stringVar == 'null')
```

or if you want to check if your string is null, then

```
if (stringVar == null)
```

Comment: yes , i mean 'null' ,i have use == checked ,well  done

Comment: Getting error "The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.
Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement"

Answer (score 4):

Checking if the string is null:

```dart
if (s == null) {
    …
}
```

Checking if the string is not null:

```dart
if (s != null) {
    …
}
```

Returning the string if not null, 'other value' otherwise:

```dart
return s ?? 'other value'
```

Assigning a value to the string only if that string is null:

```dart
s ??= 'value'
```

Calling a method (property) on the string if it's not null

```dart
s?.length
```

Comment: Not working, getting error "The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.
Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement"

Comment: That's because you're using the newest Dart with sound null-safety.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Kindly update your answer as per the newest Dart with sound null-safety. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no need to update the answer. The situation under question is impossible with sound null safety if you're using non-nullable strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [isEmpty property](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/String/isEmpty.html).

```
bool [string name] isEmpty;
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
String text = "text"; 
print(text.isEmpty);
```

Output: `false`

Edit: I believe that Mohammad Assad Arshad's answer is more accurate. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to

```
myString == 'null'
```

or

```
myString == null
```

There is another meaning that "null" could take: the null character. In ASCII or Unicode this has the code value of `0`. So you could check for this value like so:

```
myString == '\u0000'
```

or

```
myString.codeUnits.first == 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time the application does not work especially when you are using `Future<String>` return type 
the below code seems to work

`myString == "null";` 
`myFinalString = ["", null, "null", "\"null\""].contains(myString);`
`print(myFinalString)` 

Output:
`=>true`